# R: deleting columns where certain percentage of values is missing

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, na, missing-data

I'm working with a data frame resembling the extract below.

**sample.df**

```
Obs   Var1 Var2 Var3
A0001 21   21   21
A0002 21   78   321
A0003 32   98   87
A0004 21   12   54
A0005 21   13   45 
A0006 21   87   45
B0007 84   NA   45
B0008 21   NA   98
B0009  2   NA   45
B0010 12   NA   45
```

I would like to remove columns with certain percentage of variables missing, for instance 80%. I tried the code below:

```
sample.df.cln <- apply(sample.df, 2, function(x) {
  if (sum(is.na(x)) / nrow(x) > 0.8) {
  x <- NULL  
  }
})
```

But it returned the following error:

```
Error in if (sum(is.na(x))/nrow(x) > 0.8) { : argument is of length zero
```

I will appreciate any help. I was also thinking that it would be beneficial to encapsulate the code in a function so it can be applied to different data frames.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that assigning a value within a function does not change the value outside of the function. So, when you do "x<-NULL" in your function, you are not actually changing the value of the input

Comment: Atomic vectors do not have a value for `nrow`. You need to use  `(sum(is.na(x))/length(x)`  . Would also be better ti use `lapply` since the `apply` function often mangles data.frames. You should also search before posting questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x <- sample.df[ lapply( sample.df, function(x) sum(is.na(x)) / length(x) ) < 0.1 ]
```